# Ancestry software availability

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an application dealing with ancestry on Ubuntu?

Wine will not co-operate with Family Tree Maker.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I will be able to give Windows the 
complete "Heave-Ho".

Answer (score 2):

**Native clients**

[GRAMPS](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080403135952698/GRAMPS.html) Genealogical Research and Analysis Management Program

```
sudo apt-get install gramps
```

[image]

[LifeLines](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144450687/LifeLines.html)  Console based genealogy software to help with family history research

```
sudo apt-get install lifelines
```

**Web**

[PhpGedView](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144945115/PhpGedView.html) Web-based genealogy viewer and editor. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpgedview/files/latest/download)

[image]

[GeneoTree](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/200908241451261/GeneoTree.html)  Genealogy software in PHP / MySQL. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geneotree/)

[image]

[GeneWeb](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090826141442235/GeneWeb.html)   Uses very efficient techniques of relationship and consanguinity computing. [To download](http://opensource.geneanet.org/projects/geneweb/repository)

**Java**

[GenealogyJ](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144533532/GenealogyJ.html)    Full-featured viewer and editor for genealogic data. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genj/files/)

[image: enter link description here]